# Particular Enumerate style

Tags: enumerate, itemize

There is a way in order to reproduce this style listing with "enumerate"? In particular a want to itemize those integral with white numbers in a red rectangle and without using always the double $$ to put them in math mode (I want each '\item' to be alrady in math mode.) [image]

Comment: The formatting of the numbers is easy to do with `enumitem`. For the automatic math modeit wouldn't be easy, to say the least. It would imply replacing the `\item` command with another command displaying the numbers, then taking the integral as a second argument. This amounts to replacing a pair of  `$` with a pair of braces. What's the difference?

Comment: Thank you but what I need is some ambient that have after '\item' all the text in math mode

Comment: Where would the math mode stop?

Comment: @AndreaLeo You should not use $$, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two solutions:

One  with enumitem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, cabin}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{\kern0pt\mathrm{d}}\mkern-2mu{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\colorbox{Tomato}{\makebox[2em][r]{\arabic*}}, wide=0pt, labelsep=0.5em, leftmargin=*, font=\bfseries\large\sffamily\color{white}, before=\everymath{\displaystyle}]
  \item $\int\sqrt{1 + x^2}\dd x$. 
  \item $\int\sqrt{1 + 4x^2}\dd x$. 
  \item $\int\sqrt{1 + 4a^2x^2}\dd x$. 
  \item $\int\sqrt{3 + 2x^2}\dd x$. 
  \item $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2x^2}}\dd x$. 
  \item $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-2x}}\dd x$. 
  \item $\int\frac{\dd x }{\sqrt{2x^2 + x + 1}}$. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The other with `tabularx`, entering mathmode in `displaystyle`. I define a `mathtablist` environment, which is a tabularx which increments a counter at each new row and displays it at the beginning of the row. This counter is referable with a label:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, cabin}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{tabenum}
\newenvironment{mathtablist}%
{%
\setcounter{tabenum}{0}\everymath{\displaystyle}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.5ex}\noindent%
\tabularx{\linewidth}%
{@{}>{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\colorbox{Tomato}{\makebox[2em][r]{\bfseries\large\sffamily\color{white}\arabic{tabenum}} }\hspace{0.6em} \arraybackslash$ }X<{$}@{}}
}%
{%
\endtabularx
\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
}%

\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{\kern0pt\mathrm{d}}\mkern-2mu{}}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Solve integral \ref{int-5}

\begin{mathtablist}
  \int√{1 + x²}\dd x. \\
  \int√{1 + 4x²}\dd x. \\
  \int√{1 + 4a²x²}\dd x. \\
  \int√{3 + 2x²}\dd x. \\
  \int\frac{1}{√{1 + 2x²}}\dd x.\label{int-5} \\
  \int\frac{1}{√{x²-2x}}\dd x. \\
  \int\frac{\dd x }{√{2x² + x + 1}}.
\end{mathtablist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is cool! There is a way to avoid $$  each time?

Comment: I don't see with a list, unless you want to replace it with `{` `}`. It could be done with `tabularx` and `listliketabs`. What's the problem with typing a pair of `$`? With a good editor, you only have to type one.

Comment: @Andrea Leo: I've updated my answer to add a solution which doesn't require typing `$` `$`.

Comment: @Bernard How can I replace the ractangles by a circles with numbers is put at centre at circles?

Comment: @Bernard There is a problem. I can't use that ambient more then 1 time in the document because of: 
Error: Command \c@tabenum already defined. \begin{mathtablist}

Comment: \newcounter{tabenum} must be outside of the ambient definition

Comment: @Andrea Leo: You're perfectly right. The reason for having for gotten is I first tested whether the code worked   in the document body, without any  environment, then turned it into an environment, and didn't check further.  It's fixed now. Thanks for pointing the problem! B.t.w., note the second way doesn't break across pages.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,enumitem}

\newlength\myboxwd \setlength\myboxwd{2em}

\setlist[enumerate]{labelwidth=\myboxwd,
  label={%
    \colorbox{red}{%
      \makebox[\myboxwd][r]{%
      \textcolor{white}{\bfseries\sffamily\arabic*}%
    }%
  }%
}%
}

\newcommand{\iitem}[1]{\item \ensuremath{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two

\iitem {2 + 2 is a math expression} \ldots but this isn't
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As Bernard more or less says: better to make a new brace-delimited command for the math.

Comment: there is a way to reverse the thing?  math mode without '{}' and normal text with '{}'?

Comment: @AndreaLeo -- Probably, but not in any way that makes sense. There's a reason it's called math mode: it's a special mode that needs to be started and stopped. Good TeX practice (in my opinion) means good, regular, and human-readable input. Often this means delimited arguments. Taking away the braces may slightly(!!) speed up your writing of the document, but it comes at the cost of obfuscating the input and making it less useful in the long run. In the case with the enumerate environment, you risk making very fragile macros.

Comment: However, you can delimit the argument in non-orthodox ways. Consider: `\def\xxx#1/{\item \ensuremath{#1}}` and then use `\xxx 2 + 2 is a math expression / \ldots but this isn't`.